# MixItUp multi-dimensional filtering

Tags: jquery

I'm using the jQuery plugin MixItUp to get some filtering on a list of content I have.

Basic single-dimensional filtering works fine, but I'm trying to use multi-filtering and do not have too much luck with getting it right.

Here is my markup:

```
<div id="page-nav-main" class="clearfix">
    <nav id="menuBrands">
        <ul>
            <li><span>
                <h5>Filter Brands: </h5>
            </span></li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter="all"><a href="#">Show All</a></li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter=".bfs"><a href="#">BusinessForSale.com</a></li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter=".fs"><a href="#">FranchiseSales.com</a></li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter=".ps"><a href="#">PropertySales.com</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav id="menuBanners">
        <ul>
            <li><span>
                <h5>Filter Banners: </h5>
            </span></li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter="all"><a href="#">Show All</a></li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter=".leaderboard"><a href="#">Leaderboards</a></li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter=".skyscraper"><a href="#">SkyScrapers</a></li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter=".mpu"><a href="#">MPUs</a></li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter=".doublempu"><a href="#">DoubleMPUs</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do: when clicked on BusinessForSale and Leaderboards to show only this type within the BFS category.

Here's my script:

```
$(function () {
    $('#Container').mixItUp({
        load: {
            filter: 'all'
        },
        controls: {
            toggleFilterButtons: true
        }
    });
});
```

I would very much appreciate the kick in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding toggleLogic: 'and' (it defaults to 'or'...)

```
 controls: {
            enable: true,
            toggleFilterButtons: true,
            toggleLogic: 'and'
        }
```

Comment: thanks Eric, I've found the solution in the meantime.